# How do I pass a ListObject as a variable?

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

Am not that skilled at Excel/VBA and need some help.  The code below (in its simplest form) throws a runtime error (13) stating I have a type mismatch.  I don't understand how it's mismatched since I've declared them as the same type.  Any ideas?

```
Sub Setup_ListObject()
    Dim the_list As ListObject
    Do_stuff_with_ListObject (the_list)  ' ** runtime error highlights "type mismatch"
End Sub
Private Sub Do_stuff_with_ListObject(ByRef a_list As ListObject)
    ' here we do stuff
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the brackets. Use this

```
Do_stuff_with_ListObject the_list
```

or if you want to use brackets then do this

```
Call Do_stuff_with_ListObject(the_list)
```

Comment: Wow - that does the trick.  In the VBA IDE when you start to type a left-bracket after the process name it shows a tooltip with a completed bracket and the variable to be passed ... that's a little misleading.  Thanks